# ESP32 video recording to SD card

Tags: esp32

So I'm trying to record a video to SD card using ESP32 with ov7670 but I don't know how to transmit pictures that are taken periodically by the camera to SD card, in a video format. I will later transmit that video to my phone over bluetooth so the video must be a video format that I can play with my phone, not a picture array. Can you guys give me advice?

Comment: Welcome aboard. I suspect that this question is off-topic here. If you are just looking for an app or a source code directory, you would be better off at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

You could try writing an MJPEG stream, which is pretty universally supported in web browsers both on desktops and mobile devices. The writer code isn't that complex and could definitely be run on ESP32. Obviously the compression isn't that great for a video stream, but i'm assuming you have a fairly low resolution and frame rate that you are looking for anyway?

More complex well compressing formats like h264 would be overkill for this, and ESP32 wouldn't have the necessary processing power to even run them at any acceptable rate.